# Books to improve mathematical problem solving abilty

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

I don't want books like "How to solve it". Instead I am looking for books that actually have problems in them. And preferably solutions too. Basically books with problems that help you develop mathematical problem solving ability.

For my background, I have graduated from high school and know high school math fairly well. But lot of the problems at high school level are reiterative and can be done by memorizing stuff. I am looking for problems that challenge you and at the same time make you a better problem solver.

Comment: I have one more recommendation. Should I edit my previous question to include it or write a new answer?

Comment: @epic_math You could edit your answer

Comment: Schaum's Outline Series is my recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The art and craft of problem solving](https://www.amazon.in/dp/111852313X/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_IquSFbR9ZHTV8) by Paul Zeitz is a very good book and it meets your requirements. It has many head scratching problems which are easy to understand but hard to do.
[The IMO compendium](https://www.amazon.in/dp/1441998535/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_7BuSFbM3MXK0D) is also a good book, which includes the questions (and answers) from the previous IMO, as well as some additional questions. It also teaches some concepts.

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is a very good book that does what you want: "[How to Prove It](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009XBOBL6)" by Daniel Velleman. It will not be as challenging as olympiad problems, but is definitely a good place to get started.